# CSS list items not centered

Tags: html, css, sass, haml

I'm working on a website where I have a `ul` menu with list items. I want the items to be centred on the screen. But it seems like my lists items have an annoying offset. See image: [image]

My (`HAML`) is built up like this:

```
.menu
  %ul
    %li
      #- content
```

My (`SASS`) css looks like this:

```
.menu {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;

  ul {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    li {
      background-color: white;
      padding-top: 2em;
      .active_menu {
        border-top: 1px $red solid;
        a {
          color: $link-hover-color;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
      }   
    }    
  }

  a {
    font-family: "ff-meta-web-pro",sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;  
    &:hover {
      border-top: 1px $red solid;
    }
  }
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
  a {
    font-family: "ff-meta-web-pro",sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;  
  }
}
```

Any ideas how I can get the menu/list items to center align?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the horizontal margin and padding on the containing ul and list items to `margin:0px;` and `padding:0px` then define the individual padding or margins you need underneath them.

Also using `margin:0px auto;` in the right place should center the elements you specify.

Comment: What I did that worked was to only add margin on one side of the li element: `margin: 0 2em 0 0;`, a bit strange and quirky.

Comment: It's because <li> elements automatically have padding added by browsers, sometimes also margin depending on the browser.